# how do i remove a duplicate lines in a list using a function?

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

```py
def remove_repeated_lines(data):
    lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
    d=[]
    for t in data:
        if t not in lines_seen: # check if line is not duplicate
                d.append(t)
                lines_seen.add(t)
    return d

a=[{'name': 'paul', 'age': '26.', 'hometown': 'AU', 'gender': 'male'},
{'name': 'mei', 'age': '26.', 'hometown': 'NY', 'gender': 'female'},
{'name': 'smith', 'age': '16.', 'hometown': 'NY', 'gender': 'male'},
{'name': 'raj', 'age': '13.', 'hometown': 'IND', 'gender': 'male'}]

age=[]
for line in a:
    for key,value in line.items():
        if key == 'age':
           age.append(remove_repeated_lines(value.replace('.','___')))

print(age)
```

the output is
`[['2', '6', '___'], ['2', '6', '___'], ['1', '6', '___'], ['1', '3', '___']]`

my desired output is `['26___','16___','13___']`

Here is my code to remove repeated lines from the value of a dictionary. After I run the code, the repeated lines are not remove.

Comment: Post the contents of the list

Comment: @bigbounty I have posted the details of my code

Comment: Are the desired outputs supposed to have one underscore, or three? If they are only supposed to have one, then why replace the period with three underscores instead of one in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can use set comprehension to do it with ease, in a more readable fashion:

```
age = list({
    line['age'].replace('.', '___')
    for line in a
    if 'age' in line
})
```

**Output:**

> `['26___', '16___', '13___']`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [37]: a=[{'name': 'paul', 'age': '26.', 'hometown': 'AU', 'gender': 'male'},
    ...: {'name': 'mei', 'age': '26.', 'hometown': 'NY', 'gender': 'female'},
    ...: {'name': 'smith', 'age': '16.', 'hometown': 'NY', 'gender': 'male'},
    ...: {'name': 'raj', 'age': '13.', 'hometown': 'IND', 'gender': 'male'}]

In [40]: set(i["age"].replace(".","")+"_" for i in a)
Out[40]: {'13_', '16_', '26_'}
```